# Excel Sheets Comparison

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having difficulty in making comparison and replacing value in excel. It would be great if someone can help me out and guide me.

There are ticket no's in both the sheets. I would like to compare ticket number, if they matches then copy type and subtype from sheet1 to sheet2 type and subtype column. I am attaching image for your reference

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to use VBA, this may help you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws1LastRow As Long, i As Long, ws2LastRow As Long, y As Long
    Dim ws1TicketNo As String, ws2TicketNo As String, ws1Type As String, ws2Type As String, ws1SubT As String, ws2SubT As String

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ws1LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ws2LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To ws1LastRow

        ws1TicketNo = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
        ws1Type = ws1.Range("B" & i).Value
        ws1SubT = ws1.Range("C" & i).Value

            For y = 2 To ws2LastRow

                ws2TicketNo = ws2.Range("A" & i).Value
                ws2Type = ws2.Range("B" & i).Value
                ws2SubT = ws2.Range("C" & i).Value

                If ws1TicketNo = ws2TicketNo Then
                    ws2.Range("B" & i).Value = ws1Type
                    ws2.Range("C" & i).Value = ws1SubT
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next y

    Next i

End Sub
```

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet 2:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

With that formula, you can search each ticket number from sheet2, search the info in sheet1 and return the value you want (type or subtype).

Something like `=VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet1!$A$2:$B$4;2;FALSE)` should work for you. adap it to your needs